# ACRA email sender

Tags: android, acra

Hi ACRA email sender not working! but toast interaction works fine.

This is my gradle:

```
implementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:5.5.0"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:5.5.0"
```

I initialize ACRA is Application class:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);

    CoreConfigurationBuilder builder = new CoreConfigurationBuilder(this);
    builder.setBuildConfigClass(BuildConfig.class).setReportFormat(StringFormat.JSON);
    builder.getPluginConfigurationBuilder(ToastConfigurationBuilder.class).setResText(R.string.errorText).setEnabled(true);
    builder.getPluginConfigurationBuilder(MailSenderConfigurationBuilder.class).setMailTo("farhadkargaran1984@gmail.com").setEnabled(true);
    ACRA.init(this, builder);
}
```

As I mentioned when crash occurred, the toast is shown to the user but email never sent even after reopening the app.
whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Tried sending to non Gmail account?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes I have tried yahoo too, not working

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I find the solution, the issue was with the last release of ACRA!!! I used 5.4.0 version instead and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the 5.5.0 release of ACRA not work for me, I changed it to:

```
implementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:5.4.0"
implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:5.4.0"
```

then it works!